# Trouble inserting data with PHP and Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have been at this for few hours now and need some help. I am a little new to jquery -  it seems straightforward enough, but I can't get this to work. If I submit the data through a form straight to the php page, it works perfectly, but I can't get the ajax to execute. It is pretty simple with just one variable to send for marking an item for review. Any help is appreciated.

```
    <input type="hidden" id="flag_item" name="flag_item" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" />
    <input type="button" class="grn_button2" id="report_btn" name="report_btn" onclick="MM_changeProp('flag1','','display','none','SPAN'), MM_changeProp('flag2','','display','inline','SPAN')" value=" Report Item "/>
```

the jquery code

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','#report_btn',function(e) {
      var data = $("#flag_item").val();

      $.ajax({
       data: data,
       type: "POST",
       url: "flag.php",
       success: function(data) {
        alert("Item has been reported");
        }
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

and the php

```
$flag_item = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbgo, $_POST["flag_item"]);

$query = "SELECT flag FROM listings WHERE item_num = '$flag_item'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
if(!$result){
         die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        }
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$new_row = $row[0] + 1;
```

Comment: In your PHP do a `var_dump($_POST) and see if the data is there.

Comment: is your <form> posting? Your problem may be that you are letting the form submit without using jQuery to prevent it, therefor redirecting and not letting the jQuery to resolve.

Comment: this contains way too many errors

Comment: I bypassed the jquery and it is getting passed, seems to be getting hung up in the jquery part

Comment: When I remove the jquery, add the form tag and send it to the flag.php page it works as expected. I am just using the button to call the jquery. When I have the form tag it just ignores the jquery. I know it has errors, which is why I am here. Can you please enlighten me?

Comment: OP just use the Ajax I gave you and add the echo at end of PHP and you're done.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the onclick you have in your button, but could you try to alert(html); instead of alert("Item has been reported"); and see if you get any errors posted inside your alert?

Answer (score 0):

You missed param name here:

```
var data = $("#flag_item").val();
```

Try this:

```
var data = {"flag_item":$("#flag_item").val()};
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it working now. I ditched the jquery I was using and started over. This jquery code is working.

```
$('#flag_form').submit(function(){
 return false;
});

$('#flag_form').click(function(){
$.post( 
$('#flag_form').attr('action'),
$('#flag_form :input').serializeArray(),
function(result){
alert("Item has been reported");
}
);
});
```

I also added the form tag and the action to input fields. Thank you for trying to help, I appreciate it.